# Cannot receive the JsonObject after I sent the data in push notification

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, notifications, push

Here I send the push:

```
ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("UserId", userId);
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
try {
    data.put("Name", objects.get(0).fetchIfNeeded().get("Name").toString());
    data.put("Amount", arr.get(ii + 1));
    data.put("Date", arr.get(ii+2));
    data.put("Time", arr.get(ii+3));
    data.put("Location",  objects.get(0).fetchIfNeeded().get("Address").toString());
    parsePush.setData(data);
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
}

parsePush.sendMessageInBackground("blah blah blah", parseQuery);
```

When I try to receive it at `onPushOpen`, I cannot find the data, when I go to the JSON I get exception.

```
public class ParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            String name = json.getString("Name");
            String amount = json.getString("Amount");
            String date = json.getString("Date");
            String time = json.getString("Time");
            String location = json.getString("Location");
            i.putExtra("Name", name);
            i.putExtra("Amount", amount);
            i.putExtra("Date", date);
            i.putExtra("Time", time);
            i.putExtra("Location", location);
            context.startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference

I think manifest is good, it is not the problem, since the receiver is working, except for the data issue.

Comment: how can i make it avilable?

Comment: you got `NullPointerException error`  check why it comes and what is the meaning of that..

Comment: I don't think this is the code which is causing the NPE. Could you post full logcat trace?

Comment: the logcat is realy long. do you maybe know if my code should work?